# Cross Reference Between Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I've had nothing but success when asking my questions on StackOverflow, so I have another one,

I have a string located in cell A54 from "Main" workbook, and I want to cross reference it to "1", "2", and "3" other .CSV files to see if the string already exists in those files. I'm wanting it to loop so that it creates a new string until it doesn't exist in any of the other CSV files. The basic syntax I'm sort of thinking is something like:

```
'1.csv, 2.csv and 3.csv are already open, and Main.xlsm is currently active

Do Until Workbooks("1.csv").Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Range("A54").Value, Workbooks("1.csv").Range("B:B"), 1, False) = False And _
        Workbooks("2.csv").Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Range("A54").Value, Workbooks("2.csv").Range("B:B"), 1, False) = False And _
        Workbooks("3.csv").Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Workbooks("Main.xlsm").Range("A54").Value, Workbooks("1.csv").Range("B:B"), 1, False) = False

        Range("J2").ClearContents # Basically like pressing F9 to randomize the formulas I have in the workbooks

        Loop
```

The "ClearContents" is what generates a new string in the workbook, so that's easy, but this syntax doesn't work, and I'm not too familiar about how to work across multiple workbooks.

Any ideas on how to cross reference a string from one workbook to see if it exists in 3 other already opened CSV files? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by “create a new string”? I’m not understanding how `.ClearContents` currently is even kind of doing that for you

Comment: Also to join those statements together you use the `And` keyword instead of `&` like in some other languages

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Thanks, this is just a basic syntax, the & or And doesn't make a difference but yes it should be AND. Also, the excel file uses their own formulas in the cells, so ClearContents basically acts the same as pressing F9 to update the sheet.